# Custom Query: query by post custom meta data

Tags: custom-field, query, post-meta

So I have a custom post called event, but I need  to query only those posts which have a custom metabox(is a checkbox) called `Show On The Homepage: and only if that checkbox is checked.

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Event','posts_per_page' => 1000 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
```

My question is there a way to query this, or I will have to do a `get_meta` in the loop and check each one with an if statement

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `WP_Query()`, you should consult [the Codex entry for `WP_QUery()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). It lists all of the parameters that can be passed to the arguments array.

In this case, you want to use the [post custom meta parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Assuming your custom meta key is `_show_on_front`, and your value is `true` or `false`:

```
<?php
$custom_query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Event',
    'posts_per_page' => 1000
    // INSERT POST CUSTOM META PARAMETERS HERE
    'meta_key' => '_show_on_front',
    'meta_value' => true
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );
?>
```

For more complex examples, consult the linked Codex entry.